# Responsive and sticky top menu conflict

Tags: javascript, css, menu, responsive, sticky

I am stuck with a conflict for a "Sticky" and "Responsive" top menu.
When it is not scrolled and I click the BARS button to open the menu (in responsive state) it works ok. If I am scrolled down and the menu is "STICKY" it lost it "position:fixed" and goes all on top (back to position:relative).

Here is my codepen :
[codepen for top navigation script conflict](https://codepen.io/Stalkium/pen/PoGWBWw)

```js
// Function that expand the top menu when collapsed (responsive)

function opennav() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");

if (x.className === "topnav")
   {x.className += " responsive";}
else
   {x.className = "topnav";}}

// This is the function that stick the menu when scrolling

window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
   if
      (window.pageYOffset >= sticky)
      {navbar.classList.add("sticky");}
   else
      {navbar.classList.remove("sticky");}
   }
```

```css
body { margin: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* Responsive CSS for the top navigation menu */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

/* Sticky CLASS that will be added when scrolling */

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="opennav()">
         <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
   </div>

   <div style="padding-left:16px">
      <!-- Put large text in this <p> to scroll -->
      <p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use float. We are not leaving in 1995. Go with flexbox or grid.

Second, your code is all over the place. Multiple script tags in HTML section, the multiple usages of the same media query... It's difficult to read your code.

Third, what you want to do can be done just by using CSS. You only need JS to open submenu. To do that just add a class.

I suggest you watch a Youtube video about the responsive menu.

Comment: Bad answer my friend, the question is not about what era we are leaving on or what the alternative, it's all about the script conflict ! That's W3school code , i am just a beginner and i just crossed their two different code one for the sticky and the second for the responsive, so i got this issue, and the float is not too obsolete as you mention, is just that flexbox is far way better, but some one can still find float enough for something, And also; it is not clever to answer someone who is asking to learn something in a Q/A forum to go learning on youtube !!!!

Comment: I know it is not well presented but it is the one from W3SCHOOLS it is meant to educationnal purposes i think, and you may notice i am really really beginner in CSS and webdesign in general, i am analyst programmer in desktop and mobile application under RAD Studio (Delphi) my problem is i never turned to webdesign until let say, 1 or 2 months before, anyway sorry i will try to reedit it and comment the section where the problem is

Comment: code Edited, i have done my best, still with Float, i must start with them to move to flexbox

Comment: W3SCHOOLS has a lot of old-school codes. There are way easier, more practical and more modern ways to create those things. That's why I keep saying Youtube is a better place to start. We can help you here if you stack on something more specific, but your current problem is bigger than that.